# No output when executing a method/function in Python

Tags: python, variables

There is no output on command line. Also the variable `input` cannot be set.

I've tried removing the variable from class, same result.

```py
class test:
    input = ""

    def __init__(this, input):
        this.input = input

    def output(this):
        print(this.input)

obj = test("hallo")
obj.output
```

I expect the output to be `hallo`.

Comment: You have to **call** the method: `obj.output()`

Comment: No idiots here, in fact it is a common mistake that even really experience coders made. Sometimes we just forget ;)

Comment: Upvoting as it's a good question with a clear problem statement and demonstrates effort made to solve the problem. Also, as a common mistake, this has potential to help other users. I've made a small edit to the title so that others with the same problem have a better chance of finding this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call the method, not just refer to it:

```
obj.output()
```